# Checkbox in a header cell in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to have a simple column header with a checkbox that selects/ deselects all rows in a QTableView. Clicking the check box in the header causes either to select or deselect all rows.

[image]

When I want to add a check box in a table cell, I have to just return the check state for the Qt::CheckStateRole in the data(..) for the required model indices as below. This is working as expected.

```
QVariant MyModel::data( const QModelIndex & rIndex, int iRole) const
{
    ...

    if (iRole == Qt::Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        return checkstate;
    }

}
```

But when I want to add a checkbox in a header cell, the above method is not working. Hear is my sample code.

```
QVariant MyModel::headerData( int iSection, Qt::Orientation eOrientation, int iRole) const
{
    ...

    if (iRole == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        return checkstate;
    }

}
```

The QTableView does not call headerData() function in my model with the Qt::CheckStateRole, as it does with data() function.

Why is this behavior? How can I insert a check box in a header cell by only modifying my custom table model?

(I do not want to create a custom QTableView or QHeaderView for this purpose)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it — Qt doesn't support check boxes in headers by default. You can read [How can I insert a checkbox into the header of my view?](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_insert_a_checkbox_into_the_header_of_my_view.3F) for further information and its realization using a custom `QHeaderView`:

> **How can I insert a checkbox into the header of my view?**
>
> Currently there is no API to insert widgets in the header, but you can paint the checkbox yourself in order to insert it into the header.
>
> What you could do is to subclass QHeaderView, reimplement [paintSection()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#paintSection) and then call [drawPrimitive()]([http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawPrimitivewith]](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawPrimitivewith%5D) `PE_IndicatorCheckBox` in the section where you want to have this checkbox.
>
> You would also need to reimplement the [mousePressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#mousePressEvent) to detect when the checkbox is clicked, in order to paint the checked and unchecked states.
>
> The example below illustrates how this can be done:
>
> ```cpp
> #include <QtWidgets>
>
> class MyHeader : public QHeaderView
> {
> public:
>    MyHeader(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QHeaderView(orientation, parent) {}
>
> protected:
>    void paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const
>    {
>        painter->save();
>        QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);
>        painter->restore();
>        if (logicalIndex == 0)
>        {
>            QStyleOptionButton option;
>             option.rect = QRect(10,10,10,10);
>             if (isOn)
>                 option.state = QStyle::State_On;
>             else
>                 option.state = QStyle::State_Off;
>             this->style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &option, painter);
>        }
>
>    }
>    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
>    {
>        if (isOn)
>            isOn = false;
>        else
>            isOn = true;
>        this->update();
>        QHeaderView::mousePressEvent(event);
>    }
> private:
>     bool isOn;
> };
>
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>    QApplication app(argc, argv);
>    QTableWidget table;
>    table.setRowCount(4);
>    table.setColumnCount(3);
>
>    MyHeader *myHeader = new MyHeader(Qt::Horizontal, &table);
>    table.setHorizontalHeader(myHeader);
>    table.show();
>    return app.exec();
> }
> ```
>
> To have all your other checkboxes checked, you could use the `pressed()` signal which should be fired from the [mousePressEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#mousePressEvent) and connect it to a custom slot where you set all your checkboxes checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 7):

**First: The check state should be stored in the model.** All the tools are already there.

```
bool MyModel::setHeaderData(int index, Qt::Orientation orient, const QVariant& val, int role)
{
  if(Qt::Vertical != orient)
    return Base::setHeaderData(index, orient, val, role);

  storeCheckState(index, val);
  emit headerDataChanged(orient, index, index);
  return true;
}

QVariant MyModel::headerData(int index, Qt::Orientation o, int role) const
{
    if(Qt::Vertical != orient)
      return Base::headerData(index, o, role);

    switch(role)
    {
    ...
    case Qt::CheckStateRole:
      return fetchCheckState(index);
    }

  return Base::headerData(index, o, role);
}
```

**Second:** We toggle checked state simply by handling the click signal on the header.

```
connect(header, &QHeaderView::sectionClicked, receiver
        , [receiver](int sec)
{
  const auto index = logicalIndex(sec);
  model()->setHeaderData(index
                         , Qt::Vertical
                         , Qt::CheckState(model()->headerData(index, Qt::Vertical, Qt::CheckStateRole).toUInt()) != Qt::Checked ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked
                         , Qt::CheckStateRole);
});
```

**Third:**
At this point we have fully functional checking behavior, only part missing is the visualization. The smartest way to go is to again use the model, taking advantage of the `Qt::DecorationRole`. Here is a dummy implementation:

```
QVariant MyModel::headerData(int index, Qt::Orientation o, int role) const
{
    if(Qt::Vertical != orient)
      return Base::headerData(index, o, role);

    switch(role)
    {
      case Qt::DecorationRole:
      {
        QPixmap p{12,12};
        p.fill(Qt::CheckState(headerData(index, o, Qt::CheckStateRole).toUInt()) ? Qt::green : Qt::red);
        return p;
       }
       break;
    ...
    }

  return Base::headerData(index, o, role);
}
```

Of course, one can draw a real checkbox there using the styled drawing.

Notice, *this solution does not require sub-classing and custom widgets.*

Also, the check state is decoupled from the view/UI. The only downside is fact the visuals are handled by the model, but this is optional - any way can be used to draw the check state, the one from the alternative answers included.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a bit modified/fixed (checkbox was displayed as disabled and redrawing didn't work) code from the link in the accepted answer.

.h

```
class CheckBoxHeader : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CheckBoxHeader(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent = 0);

    bool isChecked() const { return isChecked_; }
    void setIsChecked(bool val);

signals:
    void checkBoxClicked(bool state);

protected:
    void paintSection(QPainter* painter, const QRect& rect, int logicalIndex) const;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    bool isChecked_;

    void redrawCheckBox();
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "CheckBoxHeader.h"

CheckBoxHeader::CheckBoxHeader(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget* parent /*= 0*/)
    : QHeaderView(orientation, parent)
{
    isChecked_ = true;
}

void CheckBoxHeader::paintSection(QPainter* painter, const QRect& rect, int logicalIndex) const
{
    painter->save();
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, logicalIndex);  
    painter->restore();
    if (logicalIndex == 0)
    {
        QStyleOptionButton option;

        option.rect = QRect(1,3,20,20);

        option.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Active;

        if (isChecked_)
            option.state |= QStyle::State_On;
        else
            option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
        option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;

        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &option, painter);
    }
}

void CheckBoxHeader::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    setIsChecked(!isChecked());

    emit checkBoxClicked(isChecked());
}

void CheckBoxHeader::redrawCheckBox()
{
    viewport()->update();
}

void CheckBoxHeader::setIsChecked(bool val)
{
    if (isChecked_ != val)
    {
        isChecked_ = val;

        redrawCheckBox();
    }
}
```

usage

```
CheckBoxHeader* header = new CheckBoxHeader(Qt::Horizontal, &table);
table.setHorizontalHeader(header);
// handle signal if needed (to set checkboxes in all rows, etc.)
//connect(header, &CheckBoxHeader::checkBoxClicked, this, &MyForm::on_header_checkBoxClicked);
```

Comment: This answer was ported to python with pyqt and then improved, see [Adding checkBox as vertical header in QtableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932528/adding-checkbox-as-vertical-header-in-qtableview/30934160#30934160)