# Indexing Header in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

recently, I try to implement checkbox on the Header of QTableWidget.

finally, I made checkbox only in first row and try to change row of checkbox but failed.

here is my code :

```
m_tableWidget = new TableWidget(ui.frame, this);
m_pAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui.frame_2, "geometry");

QSizePolicy policy = m_tableWidget->sizePolicy();
policy.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed);
m_tableWidget->setSizePolicy(policy);
m_tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);

pCheckBoxHeaderApplication = new CheckBoxHeader(Qt::Horizontal, m_tableWidget);
m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeader(pCheckBoxHeaderApplication);

m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QTableWidgetItem("X"));
m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QTableWidgetItem("Y"));
m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QTableWidgetItem("Z"));
m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, new QTableWidgetItem("Velocity"));
m_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, new QTableWidgetItem("Use"));
m_tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(4, new CheckBoxDelegate(m_tableWidget));
m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);
m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Stretch);
m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);
m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::Stretch);
m_tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView::Stretch);
m_tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
m_tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(30);
```

I want to make this :

[image]

and I referenced this code from [Checkbox in a header cell in QTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557913/checkbox-in-a-header-cell-in-qtableview/38806510)

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah I edit some contents for example. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem like this

```
void CheckBoxHeader::paintSection(QPainter* painter, const QRect& rect, int nLogicalIndex) const
{
    painter->save();
    QHeaderView::paintSection(painter, rect, nLogicalIndex);
    painter->restore();
    if (nLogicalIndex == m_nIndex)
    {
        QStyleOptionButton option;

        option.rect = QRect(m_nCurruentIndexPosX, 3, 20, 20);

        option.state = QStyle::State_Enabled | QStyle::State_Active;

        if (m_bIsChecked)
            option.state |= QStyle::State_On;
        else
            option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;
        option.state |= QStyle::State_Off;

        style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_IndicatorCheckBox, &option, painter);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for commenting I found problem and fixed it.